# Code sign XLSM file with PFX certificate in reactjs or nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, code-signing, pfx, xlsm

I have an xlsm file which is generated programmatically on  a click event. Also I have a pfx certificate. I would like to sign the xlsm file with pfx certificate programmatically using either reactjs/ nodejs. Any help would be appreciated.

Whenever an xlsm export is triggered from my application the downloaded xlsm should be digitally signed with the given pfx certificate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a dataset which is exported as an XLSM (Macro-enabled) file. What I need is to add a pfx certificate to the exported xlsm file